# ServerlessError: The "key" argument must be one of type Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, string, or KeyObject. Received type undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have an issue with serverless.

I created a simple template with this command line :

> serverless create --template aws-nodejs

then i run the commande line to deploy the serverless,

> serverless deploy -v

but i receive this error :

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  ServerlessError: The "key" argument must be one of type Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, string, or KeyObject. Received type undefined

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           11.11.0
     Serverless Version:     1.38.0
```

I don't understand why it can't deploy my lambda function ?

Comment: please post your serverless.yml file

Comment: you can run SLS_DEBUG=* sls deploy -v. This might give you more info